Looking for a short sharp pin
I'm looking for a short pin with a sharp point, to be used for probing a circuit. Similar to a scope probe tip, but for a dedicated custom PCB.
Ideal length of <5mm, diameter of <1mm, solderable. Preferably not a spring contact, but that could be OK.
I have looked on Digikey and Mouser without success.
Part numbers or any similar suggestions are very welcome

Raid the sewing kit of wife / mistress / girlfriend / sister... Made many from needles etc. One really good one was by using the injector needle from a diesel injector - very hard and was a good scribe as well.

Or husband / buddy / boyfriend / brother / father... All of my applicable above are better seamsters than me and a lot of the female equivalents.

How sharp is sharp, here? Micromanipulator (among others; they're the one my workplace uses) sells beryllium copper probes (which you could cut to length) with a very fine (sub-micron radius, if you want) tip. Note that their standard probes are tungsten, which isn't solderable; you'll need to get one of the beryllium copper ones. They're intended for probing semiconductor wafers, but nothing says you can't use them for other purposes. They aren't cheap, so if you don't need it that sharp you should look for something else.

@Hearth GGB sells sharpened thin tungsten wires embedded in in a thick 2" long copper rod  (of 0.02" ~0.5mm  diameter). eg. 10$\mu$m diameter with tip radius < 0.1$\mu$m. They are "disposable" but not all that cheap and come in 5's. As you say, for probing chips, definitely not PCBs as we normally speak of them.

If you don't mind slightly blunt, but tapered tips: 
Wire-wrap pins come gold plated and are 0.64 mm square. 
Header pins are 0.64 mm sq. for 0.1 inch headers, 0.5 mm sq. for 2 mm headers, 0.4 mm sq. for 0.050 inch headers.
You can push the header pins from the carrier.
Circular Connector Contacts have rounded tips and are sold as individual items.
Spring-tipped pins (Pogo Pins) come in all sorts of tip styles from rounded, cup, waffle, to very pointy in various diameters. You can get sockets for Pogo Pins so you can replace the contact easily. Digikey, Mouser, & Sparkfun carry these.
Some parts from the junk box:

From left to right: 0.1 inch header, dome-headed pogo pin, waffle-headed pogo pin, 2 mm header.

As others have said tailoring pins can be got retail for cheap at any place that sells sewing supplies.  don't buy stainless steel, get the tin or zinc plated ones.
Map pins are a shorter alternative available from places that sell stationery
insulation piercing probe tips are another alternative
